# Going through a file

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a program that receives 2 strings, an input and output string. The input string is a name of a text file that contains instructions on the height and length of a grid, a runner's starting location on the grid, and then direction they move and how many spaces they move. I've managed to get the grid and starting location out of the text file however I am having trouble using the instructions to move the runner. Here is my code:

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int i = 0;

    for(String keep : s.split(" ")){
        if(i==4){
            break;
        }
        steps[i++] = Integer.parseInt(keep);
    }
    first++;
    if (first>3){
        break;
    }
}
while(in.hasNext()){
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String x = in.nextLine();
    if(s.equals("N")){
        spaces = Integer.parseInt(x);
        steps[2] = steps[2]-spaces;
    }
    else if(s.equals("S")){
        spaces = Integer.parseInt(x);
        steps[2] = steps[2]+spaces;
    }
    else if(s.equals("W")){
        spaces = Integer.parseInt(x);
        steps[3] = steps[3]-spaces;
    }
    else if(s.equals("E")){
        spaces = Integer.parseInt(x);
        steps[3] = steps[3]+spaces;
    }
    if(steps[2]<0||steps[2]>steps[0]){
        wrt.println("lost");
        wrt.close();
        in.close();
        return;
    }
    if(steps[3]<0||steps[3]>steps[1]){
        wrt.println("lost");
        wrt.close();
        in.close();
        return;
    }
}
wrt.println(steps[2]+ "" + " " + steps[3] + "");
```

Comment: Which if statements in particular?

Comment: Sorry my bad the ones in the while loop.

Comment: We're going to need to see some example input that demonstrates the problem, I think.

Comment: If the example I just added is not enough just let me know

Comment: Is that the file verbatim? I assume not, since you're calling readline() each time, which would read the entirety of what you have posted above in one shot.

Comment: I have many different tests to go through Some have 1 line like that one and others have multiple ones.

Comment: For the case above, it's obvious why it doesn't work - the very first readLine() reads the entire file, and so when you get the the while loop with the if statements, in.hasNext() returns `false`.

Comment: Then how do I add it to my first while loop and run it through?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'it' in the sentence above. Also, you should probably explain the format of the input file in more detail.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, each line of the file will start with 4 numbers that set the area size & position, and the rest of the line is tuples of (direction, distance) right?

Comment: Correct that is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion we had in the question's comments, you need to do something along the lines of

1. Read a line from the file
2. Read the first four numbers from that line
3. Read the next character and number from the line, and do something with it
4. Return to 3) until there's no more line.
5. Return to 1) until there's no more file.

The problem with your solution is that you do 1) and 2), and then read the next line from the file before 3). If there's only one line in the file, the program then ends.

You need to change how you read the data. Look into [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), that might help you.

**Update:**

Look at this part of the code:

```
if(keep.equals("N")){
    spaces = Integer.parseInt(keep);
```

See the problem?

Also, [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) of `Scanner` might help you, rather than splitting the string.

Comment: I added my edited code above. I am only having trouble now getting the number afterwards. what would you suggest?

Comment: @Darkhail see above. Also note the StackOverflow etiquette of upvoting answers that have helped you.

Comment: Sorry I am a new user so only just today have I gained the ability to upvote.

Comment: @Darkhail No worries. "I am a new user" - that's why I mentioned it, since lots of new users don't know about upvoting / accepting answers, etc.

Comment: Uh, I didn't mean that you should accept this answer - unless the hints above solved your problem.

Comment: Well I couldn't accept ur comments as the answer but its been the entire conversation that helped me come to a conclusion that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
    String commands = in.nextLine();

    String commandArray[] = commands.split(" ");
    height = commandArray[0];
    width = commandArray[1];
    startingX = commandArray[2];
    startingY = commandArray[3];

    for(int i=4; i<commandArray.length;i+=2){
        spaces = Integer.parseInt(commandArray[i+1]);

        switch(commandArray[i]){
            case "N":
                steps[2] = steps[2]-spaces;
            case "S":
                steps[2] = steps[2]+spaces;
            case "W":
                steps[2] = steps[3]-spaces;
            case "E":
                steps[2] = steps[3]+spaces;
        }
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense with what I am trying to do. I need to update the position of where the runner is after following my instructions. The steps changes u propose update one part of where the runner is and never start the runner anywhere.